# Invoking the same rake task twice in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to test a rake task with rspec, and for that purpose I need to invoke it twice but
it is only being invoked once.

```
it 'first test' do
    Rake::Task['my_rake_task'].invoke
    # rake task was processed
end

it 'second test' do
    Rake::Task['my_rake_task'].invoke
    # rake task was NOT processed
end
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

if a rake task has already been invoked once it won't run again unless you call:

`@rake[@task_name].reenable`

or invoke it with

`@rake[@task_name].execute`

Comment: I had to use reenable since execute does not accept arguments, unlike invoke. And then had to fix it running more times then requested - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530844/3125034

Comment: I did `invoke` at `setup` and `reenable` at `teardown`

Answer (score 4):

To adding to Guy Segev answer I prefer adding this to your spec file

```
  after(:each) do
    Rake::Task["task:name"].reenable
  end
```