# Invoke rake task with arguments from another task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I would like to be able to pass arguments for a task that I have to call from another task

Invoking without arguments works for me like this:

```
Rake::Task["mytask1"].invoke
```

However with arguments like this it does not:

```
Rake::Task["mytask1[1,v18_0,20141230]"].invoke
```

Thanks

Answer (score 58, accepted):

you can try

```
Rake::Task[:my_task].invoke(1,'v18_0',20141230)
```

or you can do

```
Rake.application.invoke_task("my_task[1, 'v18_0', 20141230]")
```

Comment: Note you have to call `.reenable` to run the same task twice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639194/invoking-the-same-rake-task-twice-in-rspec

Answer (score 8):

You can pass in parameters through [invoke](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/Task.html#method-i-invoke)

```
namespace :tester do
  desc "test"
  task :test, [:amount] => :environment do |task, args|
    puts "Your amount is #{args.amount}"
  end

  task :test_task do
    Rake::Task["tester:test"].invoke(100)
  end  
end

rake tester:test_task
Your amount is 100
```